# Regular Expression find usage of word after "/" in URL

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to parse through URLs using Ruby and return the URLs that match a word after the "/" in .com , .org  , etc.

If I am trying to capture "questions" in a URL such as 
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions` I also want to be able to capture `https://stackoverflow.com/blah/questions`. But I do not want to capture `https://stackoverflow.com/queStioNs`.

Currently my expression can match `https://stackoverflow.com/questions` but cannot match with "questions" after another "/", or 2 "/"s, etc.

The end of my regular expression is using `\bquestions\`.

I tried doing `([a-zA-Z]+\W{1}+\bjob\b|\bjob\b)` but this only gets me URLs with `/questions` and `/blah/questions` but not `/blah/bleh/questions`.

What am I doing wrong and how do I match what I need?

Comment: `'/blah/bleh/questions'.match(/\/([a-z]+)\/?$/);`

Comment: Is there a certain part of the URL that you need to capture for later use, or do you just need a pattern that matches any string that ends with `/questions`?

Comment: @CAustin I have the pattern to match a URL up to the `/` but I just need the regex to match the rest of a string that ends with `/questions` or `/BLAH/questions` or `/blah/questions`. Etc.

Comment: In that case, wouldn't this simply be a matter of using `^.+\/questions$`?

Comment: @plalx I added `\/([a-zA-Z]+)\/?$` to my regex and the result matches anything after the `/`. I added the `A-Z` because I need it to match `/BLAH/questions` as well.

Comment: @CAustin I tried `^.+\/questions$` but that only gets `questions` at the end of the URL. Like `/BLAH/questions` but not `/questions/BLAH`.

Comment: @RoyValentine Well, it's because now it will also match `/queStioNs` and you do not really have a way of avoiding this.

Comment: Don't use regular expressions.  Extract it with this: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html

Comment: @squiguy I want to know how to do it with regular expressions. But thank you for the module link.

Comment: @RoyValentine Is this what you wanted, match anything after the last `/`? Btw, to make sure you pickup either all upper case or all lower case do: `\/([a-z]+|[A-Z]+)\/?$`

Comment: @RoyValentine: you never said you wanted to match URLs that end in anything other than `/questions`.  I'm pretty confused right now about what you're looking for.  Does the URL simply need to contain `/questions` at any point?

Comment: @plalx That is almost what I want but what if the URL is `https://questions.com/blah`. Would that not pick that up as a match? And is there any way to not match a URL with upper case JOB?

Comment: @CAustin Sorry about the confusion. I just want to find any URL that contains `/questions` at any point. Only lower case `/questions`. My only concern with matching any `/questions` is if the URL is `https://questions.com`

Comment: In that case, you can use a slightly modified version of what I posted above: `^.+\/questions.*$`

Comment: @CAustin Sorry I editted my last comment to say that I do not want to match `questions` in the domain name. So `https://questions.com` should not match.

Comment: @CAustin I modified your answer and now have it as `^.+[a-zA-Z]+\/questions.*$` I think this will work?

Comment: Ah, then maybe this would work for you: `^.+[^\/]\/questions.*$`

Comment: @CAustin Would you mind explaining why `[^\/]` is better than `[a-zA-Z]` or something that checks for letters and numbers. Because both your answer and my answer work on my small tests.

Comment: `[^\/]` matches anything other than a forward slash, which would prevent it from matching `https://questions.com`.  `[a-zA-Z]` matches any lowercase or capital letter, which means something like `https://stackoverflow.com/test123/questions` would be invalid.

Comment: So if I didn't want to do `[^\/]` and for some reason wanted to put in every match, I wouldn't want to do this, I would have to put something like `[a-zA-z0-9\-\.]`? Also what is `^.` doing? I would think that it gets any character at the beginning of the line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether there is any simple way around, here is my solution:

```
regexp = '^(https|http)?:\/\/[\w]+\.(com|org|edu)(\/{1}[a-z]+)*$'
group_length = "https://stackoverflow.com/blah/questions".match(regexp).length
"https://stackoverflow.com/blah/questions".match(regexp)[group_length - 1].gsub("/","")
```

It will return `'questions'`.

**Update as per you comments below:**

use `[\S]*(\/questions){1}$`

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I tried your expression and it worked but it also picked up anything I typed in such as `http://this.com/blah`. Someone else in my question's comments provided me with the answer. It was `^.+[^\/]\/questions.*$`

Comment: I thought you need the word after '/', and I did take 'questions' as an example.

Comment: @RoyValentine: this '^.+[^\/]\/questions.*$' returns the whole URL, right? not the word you have asked for. Also it will not validate the protocol portion, it also takes 'htt://this.com/blah/questions'. So, how that can be valid?

Comment: I did not need just the `questions`. I needed the whole URL. And I see that that my regex will not validate the URL but I am not trying to validate the URLs with this regex. If I needed to I assume I would add the `(https|http)` part and the `(com|org|edu)`?

Comment: Is 'https://this.com/blah/questions....' also acceptable for you (last dots you can see)? (^.+[^\/]\/questions.*$)

Comment: I guess technically that shouldn't be valid but in one regex line how can I capture the URL for what I want? Without the ... I guess.

Comment: If it really helped you, please accept it for future references.

Answer (score 4):

You don't actually need a regex for this, you can instead use the [URI module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html):

```
require 'uri'

urls = ['https://stackoverflow.com/blah/questions', 'https://stackoverflow.com/queStioNs']

urls.each do |url|
    the_path = URI(url).path
    puts the_path if the_path.include?'questions' 
end
```